# What is the meaning of this sentence in the Nikki's Sudden book

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Between Anto and Lizzie **the balance was tipped between my vegetating away** until the Swell maps royalties ran out  and actually getting around to making a new record.

Extract from Nikki Sudden the last bandit

Does it mean that Anto and lizzie were ok with the "vegetating life" of Nikki until he did not receive Swell Maps  royalties (Swell Maps was the first band of  Nikki).

What does the bold sentence mean? Why my vegetating "away"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The balance was tipped* means that there were two alternatives that were roughly equally appealing (or equally unappealing), and something caused the people to choose one of the alternatives. Here the alternatives are "my vegetating away until the Swell maps royalties ran out" and "actually getting around to making a new record".

The expression does not indicate which way the balance was tipped: only semantic clues (like the word "actually") allow me to conclude that it probably means that they decided to make a new record.

*Vegetating away* is not an established expression: the *away* expresses a judgment that it would be useless, or a waste of a life.